# What's underused by Americans?

Tags: riddle

Underused by Americans,
Lucky from below an animal,
Plucking at your tin cans,
Sequential in this riddle.
Do you know what I am?
Can you find my shape?
If so, you truly know yourself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> the letter U.

*Underused by Americans,*

> Colo(u)r, valo(u)r, etc.

*Lucky from below an animal,

Plucking at your tin cans,*

Kit-Ginevra's answer (go upvote it if you like this one) observes that

> line 2 is surely talking about horseshoes; perhaps then line 3 is talking about horseshoe-shaped magnets used for separating tin cans and other ferromagnetic metal items from landfill? Or U-shaped can openers (which I think exist but aren't exactly the norm)? ... OP's remarks in comments suggest that line 3 is referring to magnets but not specifically to anything to do with rubbish separation; perhaps the point is simply that (often-horseshoe-shaped) magnets will exert a force on many "tin cans" since despite the name they are usually made mostly of steel.

*Sequential in this riddle.*

> First letter of the first line. Second letter of the second line. Third letter of the third line. Etc.

*Do you know what I am?

Can you find my shape?

If so, you truly know yourself.*

> You know "you". (Perhaps there is more to those lines, besides the fact that "U-shaped" is a fairly standard way to describe things that are, er, U-shaped, but if so it has escaped my notice.)

Comment: Good job so far! The thing you've missed in the last few lines is also the key to the second and third lines.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Will think further.

Comment: I would leave just "Baaa!" as a comment but that's 10 characters tewe fewe.

Comment: There might certainly be a ewe in line tewe, but I'm still failing to see what's so lucky or what it has to dewe with tin cans. (I also wondered whether line 2 was hinting at under/dog but that also gets me nowhere.) "Fortunate" means lucky and contains both a ewe sound and the letters of a can of tuna, but I don't see how to turn that into something coherent either...

Comment: Ewer first guess on line 3 is more or less correct, althewe the landfill bit is off the mark. (Both lines 2 and 3 are quite obscewer, by design: I had to obfuscate them quite a bit so that they weren't simply obvious, e.g. I didn't want to mention equestrians.)

Comment: "Lucky from below an animal" = Horseshoes are shaped like a U and are sometimes considered to be lucky.

Comment: Out of curiosity: which bit was the giveaway for you? Did you spot the letters progressing right away, or did line 4 take a bit longer to work out?

Comment: The two things I noticed very quickly -- and I'm afraid I don't remember in what order -- were (1) the first line suggesting "colour" etc. and (2) the "u"s in successive positions on successive lines. (#2 didn't jump out of its own accord, but line 4 made me look for such things and then it was very obvious.)

Answer (score 17):

Lucky from below an animal is...

> A horseshoe is found below an animal,is U-shaped and is supposedly lucky.

As for plucking at your tin-cans

> A plectrum is shaped like a letter U, and I assume that tin-cans can be used as a synonym for (guitar,banjo,ukulele) strings

Comment: Line 2 is correct, line 3 isn't. (Was going to say more than that, but this puzzle is only 20 minutes old, so I'm sure someone will get it soon anyway :-) )

Comment: Ah, nice. There are horseshoe-shaped can openers and horseshoe-shaped electromagnets that might be used to remove (not-actually-tin) cans from a big pile of rubbish, I guess. Not super-convinced by either.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> Foot

*Underused by Americans,*

> The stereotype is that they are lazy? (No offense meant, I am American)

*Lucky from below an animal,*

> If an animal's feet are above them, they are probably dead.

*Plucking at your tin cans,*

> [Foot drum?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_drum)

*Sequential in this riddle.*

> Iambic foot?

*Do you know what I am?* *Can you find my shape?*
*If so, you truly know yourself.*

> You know yourself if you know the exact shape your feet

Edit:

> Oh, I didn't realize the top answer was already correct, just without the all the clues filled in.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of that particular stereotype about Americans. The idea of using the double meaning of "foot" as a body part and a unit of poetry is nice - *filing away for possible use in a future riddle* - but I'm afriad this isn't the right answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor first thing I thought of when seeing the title, -> gyms, exercise, etc. It's a stereotype based on the obesity rate of americans being one of the highest in the world (highest in major countries)

Comment: "If an animal's feet are above them, they are probably dead." Or a sloth hanging from a tree, but it's sometimes hard to tell the difference :-)

Comment: Claiming that Americans underuse feet would be a rather poorly conceived clue, since we with measure distance in feet.

Comment: "Plucking at your tin cans makes me think" of the shape of the tab on top of a soda can or sometimes food cans. That you pluck at to open. Would that be it?